# what do the symbols 'Wl,-R' and '-Wl,./lib' mean in makefile?

Tags: c++11, makefile

Here is an example of makefile:

`LINKFLAGS += -L./lib -lqn -Wl,-R -Wl,./lib`

What exactly are the symbols '-Wl,-R' and '-Wl,./lib'?

Answer (score 1):

The symbols in question have no particular meaning to `make`.  They are just text as far as it is concerned, so their meaning depends on how they are used.

If the name "`LINKFLAGS`" is to be taken as indicative, however, then these will be included among the command-line arguments to link commands `make` runs (but this is still a question of parts of the makefile that are not in evidence).  Such flags are not standardized, so the meaning is still somewhat in question.

If you happen to be using the GNU toolchain then [the `-Wl` option to `gcc` and `g++` assists in passing arguments through to the underlying linker](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options), which would be consistent with the apparent intention.  Appearing together as you show them, and supposing that `./lib` is a directory, the effect on [the GNU linker](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) is equivalent to using its `-rpath` option and specifying `./lib`.  That would be a somewhat odd thing to do, but not altogether senseless.

Answer (score 0):

[gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) indicates that `-Wl` is used to pass options to the linker.

[gnu ld documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) and [ld.so man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) indicate that `-R` does.  In summary, registering in the executable a path where shared libraries are searched when the executable is launched.  The information about `--enable-new-dtags` and `--disable-new-dtags` may be also useful in understanding what happens.

The use of `./lib` as argument of `-R` is odd, `$ORIGIN` is probably what is desired.  Thus, with the various escape mechanisms needed,

```
LINKFLAGS += -L./lib -lqn -Wl,-R '-Wl,$$ORIGIN/lib'
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are options for the linker (or the link step done by the compiler). You can find in the [man page of gcc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc).

```
-Wl,option
 Pass option as an option to the linker. If option contains commas, it is 
 split into multiple options at the commas. You can use this syntax to pass 
 an argument to the option. For example, -Wl,-Map,output.map passes 
 -Map output.map to the linker. When using the GNU linker, you can also get 
 the same effect with -Wl,-Map=output.map.
```

So, it is equivalent to pass the options `-R`and `.lib` to the linker. The [man page of ld](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) stats than `-R .lib` is equivalent to `-rpath=.lib`

```
-rpath=dir
Add a directory to the runtime library search path. This is used when linking 
an ELF executable with shared objects. All -rpath arguments are concatenated 
and passed to the runtime linker, which uses them to locate shared objects at
runtime. The -rpath option is also used when locating shared objects which are 
needed by shared objects explicitly included in the link; see the description 
of the -rpath-link option. If -rpath is not used when linking an ELF executable,
the contents of the environment variable "LD_RUN_PATH" will be used if it is
defined.
```